# Update view using Message Center?

Tags: view, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm quiet new to Xamarin.Forms.

This is to clear a doubt.

Is it possible to update view using **Messaging Center** in **Xamarin.Forms** ?

Comment: find the link bellow http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41328977/how-to-use-messaging-center-in-xamarin-forms

Answer (score 0):

The MessagingCenter is a centralized messaging service, meaning you subscribe to it, and other places raise events to it.

What you do when you receive an event is whatever you want. You can use it to update the View if you want but normally its used to update the Model and the INotifyPropertyChanged event notifies the view of any properties that have changed.

This blog article may help further.
http://www.xamarinhelp.com/messenger-service-day-7/